# How to check internet connection in android without ping or using deprecated code?

Tags: android, kotlin, connection, connectivity

I see many answer for this question but most of the answers using **deprecated code** & many using **ping** method to check active internet connection on android that results of getting wrong result on some devices like Samsung. I need a code that could be small & efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one out its simple and efficient

```
NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)youractivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (info == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(login.this,"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Part of this answer is deprecated but still it work fine, Thank you sir.

Comment: Ever heard of Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

In [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type)

```kotlin
   val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = cm.activeNetworkInfo
    val isConnected: Boolean = activeNetwork?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true
```